# How to show the results of db in html dropdown using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Hi I am new to php and ajax and I am trying to show the results of an query in the html dropdown using ajax
My php is

```
    $pro1 = mysqli_query("select email from groups");
```

Here I tried to push the results into an array but not came
now I want this array of results displayed in the dropdown

My html dropdown is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      defer
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#shareMdl"
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="shareMdl" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h3>Share with people</h3>
                <p style="color: red; display: none;" id="errUsr">
                  Please select atleast one email, to share.
                </p>
                <div id="email-list-container" class=""></div>
                
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
  <script defer>
    const emaiList = [];
    let emailListIndex = 1;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      addAddtionalEmail();

      

    function addAddtionalEmail() {
      if (emailListIndex < 9) {
        $("#email-list-container").append(
          `<div class="form-group" style="display:flex">
                  <select class="form-control" name="email" id="Email-${emailListIndex}" onkeyup="filter(this.value)" placeholder="option">
                    
                  </select>
                 
            </div>`
        );
        emailListIndex++;
      }
    }
    })
    
  </script>
</html>
```

Now I want to display the results of query in the dropdown through ajax by pushing the php results into array

My php I tried so far but not working:

```
 if($action == getEmails)
 $properties = array();
    $pro1 = mysql_query("select email from groups");
    if(mysql_num_rows($pro1) > 0)
    {
        while($proData = mysql_fetch_assoc($pro1))
        {
            $properties=$proData
            
            array_push($properties, $props);
        } 
    }
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'ok', 'props'=>$properties));
  }
```

ajax:

```
window.fillData = function(){
  alert("clicked");
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"memberslist.php",
        data:{
          action:"getEmails",
         },
         success : function(response)
        {
```

Comment: where is your <select> box?

Comment: in script tag function addAditionEmail @KUMAR

Comment: Usually, with AJAX you are doing a call to an external script, process the results of that call to the page. I don't see you doing that here. Is this all your code?

Comment: @jeroenpeters see I had edited of what I had done so far for getting but I strucked there of how to show the results in dropdown which I took

Comment: @jeroenpeters could you please help me?

Comment: @swith, it would also help to have a sample (anonymized) output of what your JSON response looks like, because this helps us understand how to loop over the results and give them back to your HTML

Comment: I would imaging your PHP script is crashing as this line apart from being unnecessary because of the line before it is using a non existing variable `array_push($properties, $props);`

Comment: Always read your error logs!

Comment: @jeroenpeters how to check the json response

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually query is correct how to push that column into array can you say please

Comment: @swith, you can see the response when you call your memberslist.php with a POST request and 'action' = 'getEmails'. Now I look at the code I see it would probably be just a list of emailaddresses, am I correct?

Comment: yes @jeroenpeters

Comment: `$properties=$proData` pushes the array returned from the FETCH into the array `$properties`, you DONT NEED the next line, the `array_push($properties, $props);` as that does the same thing so you are doing it TWICE. Oh and I didn't say the query was wrong :)

Comment: ok @RiggsFolly how to check the response of that query

Comment: As all you are sending back is a set of emails I would be tempted to do `$emails[] = $proData['email']`

Comment: ok how to show them in a dropdown using ajax @RiggsFolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I kept $emails[] = $proData['email'] I am getting ArrayArray--- like this

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: @Dharman I am getting the json like this props: [{email: "treddi@streamsol.com"}, {email: "EmilyandRich@gmail.com"}, {email: "gfinn@ucx.ucr.edu"},…]
can you say how can I get them in my dropdown according to the below answer

Comment: this is a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112308/how-to-append-the-data-from-database-to-html-select-box-using-ajax

Comment: That question was closed as I didnt focused on problem and not given chance top ask another time so I took my frnd account and asked the same question @jeroenpeters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be the way to go:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      defer
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap select -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#shareMdl"
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="shareMdl" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h3>Share with people</h3>
                <p style="color: red; display: none;" id="errUsr">
                  Please select atleast one email, to share.
                </p>
                <div id="email-list-container" class="">

                    <div class="form-group" style="display:flex">
                        <select class="form-control" name="email" id="share_by_email" data-live-search="true">

                        </select>
                    </div>

            </div>

                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script defer>
      const emaiList = [];
      let emailListIndex = 1;

      $(document).ready(function () {
        addAddtionalEmail();
      });

      /* Declare functions outside of the document-ready */
      function addAddtionalEmail() {
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          dataType:"json",
          url:"memberslist.php",
          data:{action:"getEmails"},
          success: function(data){
            /* It's probably best if you check if 'props' have been set here */

            data.props.forEach(function(email) {
                $("#share_by_email").append("<option>" + email.email + "</option>");
            });
            $('#share_by_email').selectpicker();
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The AJAX call is executed inside the `addAddtionalEmail()` function.
The code in memberslist.php could be like this:

```php
 if($action == getEmails)
    $properties = array();
    $pro1 = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `groups`");
    if(mysql_num_rows($pro1) > 0)
    {
        while($proData = mysql_fetch_assoc($pro1))
        {
            array_push($proData['email'], $props);
        } 
    }
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'ok', 'props'=>$properties));
  }
```

I am not sure why you had `if (emailListIndex < 9) {` in your code, but I assumed this was not necessary.

Comment: @ jeroenpeters actually my php is not working query is correct but how to get one column from the query into one array can you say please

Comment: @swith are you sure that is connected to the database server and is actually able to select data from the `groups` table?

Comment: @ jeroenpeters actually I had select box also in the function where you wrote ajax

Comment: please help me where should I write

Comment: It seems like you forgot a `;` in the PHP code. I also added the PHP code now in my answer

Comment: I am getting the json like this props: [{email: "treddi@streamsol.com"}, {email: "EmilyandRich@gmail.com"}, {email: "gfinn@ucx.ucr.edu"},…] can you say how can I get them in my dropdown

Comment: yes I am getting [object Object] in my dropdown see my json and help me please

Comment: @ jeroenpeters my json response is not like you showed in answer

 
props: [{email: "treddi@streamsol.com"}, {email: "EmilyandRich@gmail.com"}, {email: "gfinn@ucx.ucr.edu"},…] 

like this I am getting how can I append the emails can you please say

Comment: @swith, that is why I asked you about the JSON response before, because otherwise I need to make assumptions. I updated my answer

Comment: @ jeroenpeters after keeping this got emails but searching functionality is not working can you please say why if you dont mind

Comment: filter(keyword) the search functionality is not working is my code correct for searching can you please check and help @ jeroenpeters

Comment: Did you copy the whole HTML? I have it working here (I even forgot to change my test-html `http://creepy.nl/list.json` to `memberslist.php` ;-)

Comment: I edited the url back in my answer, please let me know if this works now

Comment: search functionality is not working I will work on it thank you @ jeroenpeters